# Unity Not Being Disposed Causing Server Lockup?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have a server farm of about 40 servers that we roll code to every couple weeks. One thing we noticed when we roll the code live is after deploying the assemblies and performing an IIS reset and put it back in the BigIp (F5) and it receives traffic the server will lockup for about 10 minutes and clients will just spin until an eventual timeout.

Looking at the perfmon we can see a dramatic spike in number of finally's and number of pinned objects btw which lead me to investigate memory issues.

So one thing I started looking into it our Unity IoC configuration. In the global.asax.cs we are registering about 15 interfaces where most are using the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager to manage the lifetime. Normally there is never a problem with the code except in this ten minute window so my first thought was a memory or resource management issue.

Does anyone know if you have to explicitly Dispose() of your Unity Container or is this handled by Unity automagically somehow? I noticed today that there was no Dispose wiring in place for Application_End so my thought was maybe when the servers are brought back on after the IIS reset there is a Unity or object resource issue until the GC comes around and frees the memory (the ten minutes it takes to come up).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Performing an iisreset will kill the currently running w3wp.exe process, so it's unlikely that not properly disposing of unity objects in `Application_End` would cause performance issues on startup. It is possible that the old web process doesn't properly release file system or other resources the new web process depends upon, but I think you'd see file access or some other errors if that were the case.

Since you're performing an iisreset, I would look closely at the code that runs when the application starts for the first time. Maybe there are some components that take alot of time to start up (i.e., say there is a singleton type class that downloads and caches a bunch of stuff from the database) that are causing the slow down, possibly only when combined with the stress of handling all of the waiting HTTP requests. Also, keep in mind that ASP.NET will incur a bunch of overhead as it compiles the application to be used the first time. Since it seems that your web application is behind a load balancer, you may want to come up with a way to "prime" the application on each individual web server before you add that web server back to the load balancer, which could be accomplished by just loading a page locally on that web server. Priming the application would allow the web app initialize itself without having to handle any outside requests, which should improve the startup time.

Long story short, I would investigate startup issues and see what I could tune there before I focused on shutdown issues.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. One thing to mention is the code in question is a seperate app within our MVC areas folder. I work on a team that has an application that lives within a much larger solution. During this ten minute window the rest of the web application works just fine which means any of the HttpModules and so forth in the web.config would load both for our application as well as the rest of the application so my thought that one of those causing a problem would affect the whole web application not just our areas folder.

Comment: Also, the big difference is our application is using Unity IoC container where the rest of the application is not. So this is what was leading me to believe there was an issue with unity handling the creation of the class. The first call though where we notice it starts to stall is a class that does some session management and it does make DB related calls. So maybe something with the SqlClient not being properly disposed since we weren't disposing the Unity instances?

Comment: Anything is possible of course, but I can't see how Unity would be a problem here. Speaking from experience, I have to think that the most likely cause for a slowdown is something your code is doing when your portion of the application is starting up. Since you say you only have 15 interfaces that are registered, add some logging that outputs the current date time around how long it takes to register these with unity, and more importantly, how long the initialization takes for each interface. Then you can look to see if one or the other has a long initialization time.

Comment: And if were debugging this issue, I still would assume the problem lies solely in the application startup code, until proven otherwise. Good luck and please keep this question updated. I'm interested to see what the cause is. Thanks.